# How can I force a coap server node to connect an specific border router?

Tags: contiki, coap

force nodes to connect to specific border router in a mesh network

Here is my setup;
6 nodes, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6 all running https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/er-rest-example/er-example-server.c Coap server
2 border router, b1, b2  running https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router connected to two Linux board (like Raspberry Pi) L1, L2.

How can I make sure that n1, n2, n3 node only connect to border router b1 and not b2, similarily, n4, n5, n6 nodes only connect to border router b2 and not b1? Thanks!

Comment: use different ip address for each router?

Comment: @kfx Those routers already have unique IPV6 addresses, I tried changing prefix also, n1, n2, n3, b1 with prefix 0xfd00 and n4, n5, n6, b2 with prefix 0xaaaa, I cannot access n4 data on L1 (Linux board to which b1 is connected) but since b1 border router has routed to L1 I can not access that n4 node on L2. I want somehow n4 to be routed by b2 and n4 data accessable on L2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change panid;

use for boarder-router b1, n1, n2, n3 panid 0xabcd

use for boarder-router b2, n4, n5, n6 panid 0xabce

*Thanks to Harald Pichler (Contiki mailing list) for this answer